# Scroll Chatwindow In a container DIV elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

In my code I have a container `<div>` where `<div>` element (Chat window) will dynamically added. It check if the total no of `<div>` (chat window) elements width exceeded the container `<div>`, if exceeded then previous and next button will appeared and scroll through the container `<div>`. But i can't figure out this issue. Any help will be appreciated.

***Here is my code:***

**Now updated this code. Now the problem is how to hide next and previous button with condition.**

```js
var chatBoxes = new Array();
var chatboxtitle= 1;



$(document).ready(function () {
    
    $("#add").click(function(){
        
        $('#container').append($('<div/>')
    .attr("id","chatbox_"+chatboxtitle)
    .addClass("chatWin")
          .html("chatbox_"+chatboxtitle)
        );
  
  
  
  chatBoxes.push("chatbox_"+chatboxtitle);
  chatboxtitle++;
 
  chk();
  
    });

})

function chk()
{
 var i=0;
 for (x in chatBoxes) {
  i++;
 }
 
 if ((i*200) > 600) {
  $("#prev").show();
  $("#nxt").show();
 }
 
}




$(document).ready(function()
    {
      $('#prev').click(function()
      {
  
   var newMargin = parseInt($("#container").css("left"))+212;
            $("#container").animate({ left: newMargin }, 50);
  
      });
      


  $('#nxt').click(function()
      {
     var newMargin = parseInt($("#container").css("left"))-212;
            $("#container").animate({ left: newMargin }, 50);
      });
   
  

   });
```

```css
#chat{
border-right: 1px solid #bac0cd;
bottom:0px;
left: 15px;
font-family: "Lucida Grande",Verdana,Arial,"Bitstream Vera Sans",sans-serif;
font-size: 11px;
height: 29px;
position: fixed;
text-align: left;
z-index: 1028;
margin-top: 8px;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 3px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 3px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 3px;
border-top-left-radius: 3px;
border-top-right-radius: 3px;
width:98%;
}


#main{
  float:right;
  height: 29px;
  width: 636px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: block;
  direction: rtl;
  left:0px;
  position:relative;
}
#container {
  float:right;
  position:relative;
  left:0px;
}
.chatWin, #buddy {

 background:color:#f2f2f4;
 border-right:1px solid transparent;
 border-left:1px solid #bac0cd;
 color:#333;
 cursor:pointer;
 height:29px;
 padding-left:10px;
 padding-top:5px;
 z-index:1026;
 border-top:1px solid rgba(29, 49, 91, .3);
 -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
 width: 200px;
 font-weight:bold; 
 display: inline-block;
 
}

#nxt{
 float:right;
 background-color:#f2f2f4;
 border-right:1px solid transparent;
 border-left:1px solid #bac0cd;
 color:#333;
 cursor:pointer;
 height:29px;
 position:relative;
 padding-top:5px;
 padding-left:2px;
 padding-right:2px;
 z-index:1026;
 border-top:1px solid rgba(29, 49, 91, .3);
 -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
 font-weight:bold; 
 display:none;
 border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}
#prev{
 float:right;
 background-color:#f2f2f4;
 border-right:1px solid transparent;
 border-left:1px solid #bac0cd;
 color:#333;
 cursor:pointer;
 height:29px;
 position:relative;
 padding-top:5px;
 padding-left:2px;
 padding-right:2px;
 z-index:1026;
 border-top:1px solid rgba(29, 49, 91, .3);
 -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
 font-weight:bold; 
 display:none;
 border-top-left-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height:900px">
  <div id="add">
   Add New
  </div>
 <div id="info"></div>
  
 </div>
 
 <div id="chat">
  
  <div id="buddy" style="float:right">Online User(0)</div>
  <div id="nxt">►</div>
  <div id="main">    
   <div id="container"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="prev">◄</div>
 
 </div>
```

Comment: **But i can't figure out this issue.** Can you please explain briefly the matter ?

Comment: I want to make fb like chat bar. in my code when click on add new automatically div added. The next prev button (◄/►) will be appeared when more than 3 chat window will present and other will be hidden, and only show when click on next prev button

Comment: You should start by binding an event `onclick` to both of your arrows. If I were you, I would add a `position : absolute` to your `<div id = chat>` in order to play with `z-index` for the nexts coming chat box.

Comment: I hope u understand my problem. Can u explain this?

Comment: The idea is to create a box which will contain your chatboxes (you did with the `<div id = "chat">`. Then, the propretie `position : relative` will permit to structure all you `<div id = "buddy">` inside, when they have the propretie `position : absolute` active. Also, in this scope you will add to your id some other `<div id = "buddy">` so you should put a `class = "buddy"` instead, because when you append to your container, you don't see them. You should append to "chat", and play with `z-index` to show one or more, and hide the others.

Comment: You could also search for caroussel, because it seems to fit with your need.

Comment: Thanks. One more things if set float:right in #container div it will break into next line not horizontally.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65683/discussion-between-zeratops-and-user1523291).